# Copy text from specific class in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have created my first python script for page scraping --> in order to visit a webpage, login, redirect to another page (navigate) and then copy a text from a specific part.

When I am trying the following it works fine:

```
copiedText = driver.find_element_by_id("random").text
print(copiedText )
```

but it is a bit more complex as the div of the text I want to copy does not have an ID. It has a class but it is not unique. When I copy the xPath in Chrome, it returns something like this:

```
//*[@id="random"]/div[12]/div[5]/div/div[2]/span
```

which is not the same everyday. The numbers **12** and **5** might be different depending on the data shown in the page (more rows in an HTML table).

So, as a plan B, I tried to use the CSS selector instead after copying it from Chrome.

but I am getting an error:

***Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:***

Is there any chance that Chrome does not give me the right one? How can I convert the outerHTML to a CSS selector in order to be 100% sure that it is correct?

The outerHTML is given below:

```
<div class="nxm-td col-total text-right" style="">
    <div class="summary-total">
        <span class="summary number">7,363.31</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the selector after copying from Chrome dev tools is here:

```
#media-grid-right > div.nxm-tr.nxm-drop.media-plan-drop.mpSummary.summary-row.no-filter > div.nxm-td.col-total.text-right
```

**UPD**

The following works fine: `Dates = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#summary > li:nth-child(1)"))).text` and this one returns no error but I am not seeing any text in the cmd: `copiedText = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#media-grid-right > div.nxm-tr.nxm-drop.drop.mpSummary.summary-row.no-filter > div.nxm-td.col-total.text-right > div > span.summary.number"))).text`

Comment: Share your CSS selector

Comment: Have you tried `span.summary.number` or `div.summary-total > span.summary.number`? Without a link to the page or more HTML, it's hard to tell what might be unique without guessing.

Comment: @Andersson It was not pasted before. Mobile problems :P I am doing it now

Comment: @JeffC The selector was not pasted before by mistake. I have updated the question. I cannot paste the link as it is a private one. The second part of the first answer below seems to be alright. I am just getting a null and not a text. No errors but I am trying to find out what is wrong with the page.

Comment: It's probably because the first element that is found by that selector is not visible or doesn't contain the text you are expecting because it's not the right element. There's probably multiple instances found by that locator. Open up the site in Chrome, open the Chrome dev tools, and see how many elements are returned by `$$("span.summary.number")`. Try the same with the other CSS selector I suggested above and see if any of them return 1.

Comment: @JeffC I have tried the same with the selector and I am only getting 1 line. I am trying innerText instead of text and I ll come back.

Comment: @JeffC In the console I can see this lines: `innerHTML
:
"7,363.31"
innerText
:
"7,363.31"`

Will it help if I paste the printscreen? I think I am missing something. Probably I have not seen that before.

Comment: So it looks like you have the right answer. Did you try Andersson's code in his answer? Did it not work? Try also the wait he suggested if the initial code doesn't return the text you want.

Comment: @JeffC It works perfectly for other parts of my page (other selectors). I will accept it soon. I am just trying to figure out why I am getting a null value. After using your line in the console, is there something that could help me? Considering that I can see the innerHTML and innerText values there, I should be getting the number. Right?

Comment: Post the relevant lines of code where you get the text off the page using the locator.

Comment: @JeffC The following works fine: `Dates = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#summary > li:nth-child(1)"))).text` and this one returns no error but I am not seeing any text in the cmd: `copiedText = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#media-grid-right > div.nxm-tr.nxm-drop.drop.mpSummary.summary-row.no-filter > div.nxm-td.col-total.text-right > div > span.summary.number"))).text`

Comment: @JeffC I will have a look tomorrow. I need to check what the lines mean in the output of the console. Maybe it is not parsable? Alternatively, I will create a report and then I will get the data using the report in Python.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer, try this one `wait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#media-grid-right > div.nxm-tr.nxm-drop.drop.mpSummary.summary-row.no-filter > div.nxm-td.col-total.text-right > div > span.summary.number").text)`

Comment: @Andersson My version now worked. I have not changed anything and it worked. Weird but it worked. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate required node by class name:

```
copiedText = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.summary.number").text
print(copiedText)
```

Also note that node can be generated dynamically, so you might need to wait until it appeared in DOM:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

copiedText = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.summary.number"))).text
print(copiedText)
```